# Were they also there?/Were they there too?

Tags: difference

"What about your parents? **Were they also there?**/**Were they there too?**"

Are these completely interchangeable in the context?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. They are interchangeable.

From https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/also

•           Also is more formal than as well and too, and it usually comes before the main verb or after be:

•           I went to New York last year, and I also spent some time in Washington.

•           In British English it is not usually used at the end of a sentence. Too is much more common in spoken and informal English. It is usually used at the end of a sentence:

•           ‘I’m going home now.’ ‘I’ll come too.’

•           . In British English as well is used like too, but in North American English it sounds formal or old-fashioned.

•           When you want to add a second negative point in a negative sentence, use not…either:

•           She hasn’t phoned and she hasn’t written either

•           . If you are adding a negative point to a positive one, you can use not… as well/ too:

•           You can have a burger, but you can’t have fries as well.

Comment: Which authority says they're interchangeable apart from you? I'm not disagreeing (or agreeing) with your answer, just pointing out that you're not an authority.

Comment: I am enough of an authority to answer this question. Are you saying I should add a reference to the interchangeability?

Comment: I have never heard of any authors, English professors, experts, etc. called Timinycricket. Who agrees that you're an authority apart from you? To everyone else you're a random person on the internet.

Comment: Okay who are you, the owner of this site? I’m just helping this person out with their english. If you have a better answer then add it. I was born and raised in the USA and have been speaking English every single day for 27 years.

Comment: As your answer stands there's no way for the OP to tell if it's correct or not. I could say "No, they're not. I'm a native speaker so you have to believe me." But that wouldn't be helpful. Just being a native speaker doesn't mean you're automatically correct about all things relating to English, and doesn't mean you shouldn't back up your statements with accepted authorities such as The Oxford Dictionary, Merriam-Webster, etc.

Comment: @CJDennis understood.

Comment: Huge improvement!